# In react hooks form, how to you copy data from one property to other of state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

This is register form, I want to send the value orgTypes>name to orgType of data of same object using `onChange` of select.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-zm1ov?fontsize=14&fbclid=IwAR06ZifrKrDT_JFb0A-d_iu5YaSyuQ9qvLRgqS20JgAcSwLtAyaOFOoj5IQ

When I use `onChange` of Select, it erases all other data of the inputs.

```
import React from "react";
import { Select } from "antd";
const { Option } = Select;

const RegisterFinal = () => {
  const data = {
    orgName: "",
    orgRegNo: "",
    orgType: "",

    orgTypes: [
      { id: "1", name: "Vendor" },
      { id: "2", name: "Supplier" },
      { id: "3", name: "Vendor and Supplier" }
    ],

    errors: {}
  };

  const [values, setValues] = React.useState(data);

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    e.persist();
    setValues((values: any) => ({
      ...values,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  };
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input
        name="orgName"
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Organization Name"
        value={values.orgName}
      />
      <input
        name="orgRegNo"
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Registration Number"
        value={values.orgRegNo}
      />

      <Select //imported from antd
        id="select"
        defaultValue="Choose"
        onChange={(select: any) => {
          setValues(select);
          console.log(select); //shows Vender/Supplier, I want this value to be sent to orgType above
        }}
      >
        {data.orgTypes.map((option: any) => (
          <Option key={option.id} value={option.name}>
            {option.name}
          </Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

When I use `onChange` of Select, it erases all other data of the inputs.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You should do it similar to the other inputs. Use the spread operator to spread out values in the callback form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setValues` function expects to take the values object as an argument. Instead you are passing the select value to it.

Instead, you can do it like this:

```
const handleSelectChange = (selectValue: any) => {
    setValues((values: any) => ({
      ...values,
      orgType: selectValue
    }));
}
```

and use `handleSelectChange` in the `onChange` of your select.

Check the solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-p9bjz

Comment: onChange={(select: any) =>
              setValues({ ...values, orgType: select })
            }

this worked as well, anything wrong with this code ?

Comment: Nothing wrong at all. I has already implemented the two solutions in the sandbox link above. One thing about the first implementation is that you can use it multiple times if you have more one than `Select` in the same component.